# Library to that allows setting of individual pixels within a window

Tags: c++

I am running Linux. I am looking for a library that will allow me to set up individual pixels within a window on screen. I am working on an embedded application and it would be a lot easier to develop my algorithms on the computer rather than the project. Im looking for something along the lines of `display.setPixel(x, y)`. Does anybody know of any similar solutions? Im looking for something using C or C++

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start with SDL:

http://www.libsdl.org/

It also has some nice image loading routines, OpenGL and other stuff you may find useful. It can be used with either C or C++.